# How to make an <input type="range> slide/drag on touch screen devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When using a standard input `type="range"` element I cannot drag the slider on a touchscreen device. I can only tap along the bar to move the slider to that point.  With a mouse I can click & drag the slider anywhere I want. Try the code out below on a touchscreen device or with emulated touch events in your browser devtools. See below for screen recordings of each behavior.

```html
<input type="range">
```

#### Desktop/Mouse Behavior

Using Firefox

[image: desktop/mouse behavior]

#### Touchscreen Behavior

Emulated touch events with Firefox's responsive design mode

[image: touchscreen behavior]

Is it possible to allow standard range inputs to respond to touch/drag events?

Comment: If it makes you feel better, it works on the Google Chrome dev tools emulator. It is possible that the issue is just Firefox's emulated tool.

Comment: There's a bug ticket for Firefox: [#1709051](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1709051).

Comment: Works fine on a real iPhone with Safari.

Comment: Working fine on a Galaxy S10 running Edge

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  The reason I first noticed this was due to it not working on my iPhone. But now I check it now and it's working! I suppose it must have been due to something else I was doing with touch events in my project.